# realm cocoa: is it possible to do queries on links

Tags: ios, swift, realm

On the following object model:

```
// Dog model
class Dog: RLMObject {
    var name = ""
    var owner = Person()
}

// Person model
class Person: RLMObject {
    name = ""
    birthdate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 1)
    dogs = RLMArray(objectClassName: Dog.className())
}
```

is it possible to query for all person's who have a dog whose name starts with 'B' i.e. something like

```
Person.objectsWhere("ANY dogs.name name BEGINSWITH 'B'")
```

I have tried it, doesn't seem to work on realm-cocoa 0.89.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, you have an extra name in the predicate statement, it should read like this:

```
Person.objectsWhere("ANY dogs.name BEGINSWITH 'B'")
```

Comment: you are right, the extra `name` was bad typing from memory :-), it works.