# Objective C Realm link query

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27724664/realm-cocoa-is-it-possible-to-do-queries-on-links) post there is a way to do this but I can't get it work on Objective C.

I want to do something like what we can do on java, please see [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries).

Can anyone point me to the right direction please?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY children.name BEGINSWITH 'A'"];
RLMResults *parents = [Parent objectsWithPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Where I have class `Parent` and `Child` and `Parent` has a `RLMArray` of `Child` objects and the name of the property is `children`.

**The model**

```
@interface Parent : RLMObject

@property RLMArray<Child> *children;
@property long Id;

@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Parent)

@implementation Parent

#pragma mark - Realm methods
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
  return @"Id";
}

@end
```

---

```
@interface Child : RLMObject

@property NSString *title;
@property long Id;

@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Child)

@implementation Child

#pragma mark - Realm methods
+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
  return @"Id";
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi Cata can you share your Parent and Child model? Also can you share what error you are seeing?

Comment: Hey yoshyosh, sorry for the late response, it seems to work with: objectsWhere method instead of using objectsWithPredicate.. I will post the model as well in a moment

Comment: objects with predicate should work if you pass a valid predicate, which the above looks like it is. Share the error message as well it helps with debugging!

Comment: Hey Cata just checking in again, were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Hey yoshyosh, thanks for your help, well I just used the other method instead of objectsWithPredicate.. In order to reproduce the issue I have to do a demo project, once I'll do that I will share it here

Comment: Sounds good, glad to hear you got it resolved. Look forward to that